# CakePHP - Call to a member function allow() on a non-object error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am creating one login authentication app in CakePHP
and getting this Fatal error: Call to a member function allow() on a non-object in /var/www/cakephp1/app/Controller/users_controller.php on line 5

and this is my controller code
**users_controller.php**

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add');
    }
    public function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('User created!');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'login'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Please correct the errors');
            }
        }
        $this->set('groups', $this->User->Group->find('list'));
    }
    public function login() {
    }
    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
    public function dashboard() {
        $groupName = $this->User->Group->field('name', 
            array('Group.id'=>$this->Auth->user('group_id'))
        );
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>strtolower($groupName)));
    }
    public function user() {
    }
    public function administrator() {
    }
    public function manager() {
    }
}
?>
```

**app_controller.php**

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => 'actions',
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'admin' => false,
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'dashboard'
            )
        ),
        'Session'
    );
}
?>
```

View **login.ctp**

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(array('action'=>'login'));
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'legend' => 'Login',
    'username',
    'password',
    'remember' => array('type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => 'Remember me')
));
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

I am using CakePHP version 1.3

Comment: Is your App Controller in the app/ directory like it should be in Cake1.3 ?

Comment: @Dave yes its in cake1.3

Comment: And your AppController file is in the app/ directory, not the app/controllers directory, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common causes for this type of error:

### The App controller file is not being loaded

If the `AppController` class doesn't exist - Cake will use a fallback for it taken from the core - it's just an empty class. For the error in the question to occur - the `Auth` component hasn't been loaded, the most likely reason for that is that the file `app/app_controller.php` either doesn't exist or a different `AppController` class file was loaded before looking for it.

This can be confirmed using [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php), e.g.:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        if (!isset($$this->Auth)) {
            debug(get_included_files());
            die;
        }
```

Look for *which* `app_controller.php` file has been loaded - if it's *not* the file containing the class in the question, that's the problem.

### Overridden constructor, not calling parent

Good children always call their parents :)

If the constructor (or any method) is overridden and does not call [the parent function](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/controller/controller.php#L358), then e.g. the components property won't get merged/set correctly or component classes won't be initialised.

If the right `app_controller.php` file is being loaded focus on the methods defined within the controller classes and check they are calling parent::methodname (for the users controller, and the app controller). Specifically verify that the Controller::__construct is being called since that's where most of the class initialization logic is in 1.3.

Answer (score 5):

1.Solution: All what you need to do is to add this line in your **UsersController**:

```
public $components = array('Auth');
```

Or

2.Soluton: In **UsersController:**

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {

}
```

and then in **AppController**:

```
public $components = array('Auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error sounds like the loading of the Auth-component failed. Have you tried removing the settings from the $components array and see if the error persists?

Comment: This kind of guess-answer is usually better as a comment (like mine above).  If it turns out to be correct, the person asking can give you more details of why it was correct, and then you can put it in an answer to be accepted.  This helps questions from filling up, and from people ignoring the question due to already having an answer.

Comment: Fair point, thanks for letting me now. Although I must confess I did look for the comment-link but couldn't find it (I do see 'link' and 'edit'), though I'm convinced I've seen that button before...

Comment: You might not yet have the ability to comment with a rep score of 1. (didn't think of that when I mentioned it to you)

Comment: @Joep how can i load Auth-component

Comment: @AjayPatel: I'd suggest making the $components array look like `array('Acl', Auth', 'Session')` And then check to see if your error persists. (to exclude the config options you're specifying there as the cause of this error (which seems unlikely, but still))

Comment: I assume the error occurs on the call APP/users/<someAction/ ?

Comment: @Dave Indeed, I just found out that commenting on other people's questions/answers is a privilege gained at 50 reputation.